# Find the volume of an intersection set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to find the volume of the intersection set $A \cap B$ whereby $ A=\{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}| x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1 \}$ and $  B=\{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}| x^2+y^2 \leq 
1/2 \}. $

It is clear that $A$ represents the unit ball centered at the origin and $B$ represents the cylinder with radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ I should at some point use the Fubini theorem. I am puzzled by intersection set. Can somebody provide a solution proposal or a comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection is what is both inside the cylinder and sphere, i.e. what is in the cylinder and below/above the caps it cuts out from the sphere.

Using the reflection symmetry in $z$ about $0$, the integral is given by
$$
2\int\int_{x^2+y^2\leq 1/2}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\mathrm dA=
2\int\int_{x^2+y^2\leq 1/2}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
And in polar coordinates
$$
4\pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}r\sqrt{1-r^2}\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta.
$$
and I leave the single variable integral to you.